# In which New Jedi Order book does Jacen see the Force on Coruscant and realises that it is neither good nor bad?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

In one of the New Jedi books, Jacen Solo (i think) follows a 'monster' and sees the source of the Force and realises that it is only one, neither good nor bad

Comment: This one? https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Jedi_Order:_Traitor

Comment: "*“Light and dark are no more than nomenclature: words that describe how little we understand.” She seemed to draw strength from his weakness, slowly managing to sit up. “What you call the dark side is the raw, unrestrained Force itself: you call the dark side what you find when you give yourself over wholly to the Force. To be a Jedi is to control your passion … but Jedi control limits your power."*, etc..

Answer (score 3):

Jacen realised this on the book Traitor which was heavily inspired by Dante’s inferno